# Is there any way to avoid duplicate page cache entries while allowing for case-insensitive URLs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, outputcache

If I have a page with outputcaching (let's call it Employees.aspx) which accepts one parameter (through querystring) called *Company* like this:

```
http://www.example.com/Employees.aspx?Company=Google
```

How can I avoid duplicate page cache entries for differently cased URLs like:

```
http://www.example.com/Employees.aspx?Company=GOOGLE
http://www.example.com/Employees.aspx?Company=GOoGlE
```

I've enabled output caching through the OuputCaching directive as follows:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="300" VaryByParam="Company"  %>
```

Is there any way to programatically set what the "unique cache key" for this particular request should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One hack-esque method of doing it would be to do a VaryByCustom (instead of VaryByParam) and do the .ToLower/.ToUpper in there.

Change the OutputCache directive to something like this:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="300" VaryByCustom="Company" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

...and add an override in Global.asax.cs for GetVaryByCustomString:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(System.Web.HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    string CustomValue = "";
    switch (custom.ToLower())
    {
        case "company":
            CustomValue = context.Request.QueryString["company"] ?? "";
            CustomValue = CustomValue.ToLower();
            break;
    }
    return CustomValue;
}
```